# How to get javascript autocomplete to work for navigator.bluetooth?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Very new to web programming and even newer to bluetooth web programming.

I was trialing some IDEs to help me out with autocomplete. But I haven't gotten any of them to work for the navigator.bluetooth namespace. Are there any tricks to getting this to work? The code is known good working in Chrome. I suspect I have to install navigator.bluetooth in the right spot for the IDE to be aware of it? (Although it is included with Chrome out of the box, so I'm not sure that's it)

I suspect the answer is trivial, thanks a lot!

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice()
      .then(device => {
        this.device = device;
        return device.gatt.connect();
```

[image: webstorm autocomplete image]

Other aspects of the autocomplete work:
[image]

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/web-bluetooth` should do it, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is type definitions for Web Bluetooth: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web-bluetooth